# Issue when using React Native Notification

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, screen, react-native-push-notification

I have an error when calling the react-native-push-notification on my screen.

caller com.akiba project needs to hold android permission SCHEDLE.EXACT-ALARM to SET exact alarms

Comment: Look like it's some permission issue. Have you added all the required permissions?

Comment: yeah this was solved but still notification not pop up ;